# How to store multiple graphs in a database?

Tags: mongodb, graph, neo4j

I need to store many independent graphs:

- Each graph with 100 to 2000 nodes
- Each node with 1 to 7 edges plus 2 to 3 extra fields.
- No directional

Right now I'm storing them as mongoDB documents with one collection for nodes and one collection for edges.

I have some questions:

1. **Does MongoDB have a "best practices" to store graphs?**
2. **Would it be better to store them in another database like Neo4j?** (It seems to be really powerful when you have really large graphs)
3. **I would like to be able to version each graph**

Comment: MongoDB 3.4 will have a new "graph traversal" feature (cf https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-3.4) - that probably will define the best practice.

Comment: I disagree that mongodb's graph traversal will define any best practice. It's just another way to traverse data (a very nice one, but by no means a "best practice" for shaping data - it's a tool in the aggregation pipeline).

Comment: As for this question, it's off topic: How you store graphs is broad and opinion-soliciting. Whether you stay with MongoDB, move to a graph-specific database (e.g. neo4j as you mentioned), or both, is again broad, and a tool-recommendation question. There's really no way to answer this objectively.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @VinceBowdren

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for your comments. I guess I should reformulate my question in a more specific way. All the documentation I've found is based on managing huge graphs but not for such a specific issue as mine.

Comment: @DavidMakogon What should I do next? Delete the question? Thanks